# Is Team Foundation Server 2010 available with Visual Studio 2010 ULTIMATE?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

According to [this](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/ultimate/overview) page, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate contain Team Foundation Server 2010. This mean we don't need to download and install TFS 2010 separately? If, yes can anyone tell me how to set up tfs 2010 with Visual Studio 2010 ULTIMATE.

Answer (score 4):

You still need to download and install Team Foundation Server, if you plan to use the Team Foundation integration that exists in Visual Studio. Installing Team Foundation Server is rather straight forward (Microsoft Wizard like), but you need to point it at an existing SQL Server instance and thus need to make sure you have a server available for use.

It's recommended that you install Team Foundation on a separate server, that's not running the database but this is in no way mandatory.

Comment: You don't "have to" point to existing SQL.  That's of course supported but will also install and use sqlexpress for you. 4GB limitation.

Comment: But the link is saying that VS ultimate include tfs server. Is this information is wrong?

Comment: Can't vouch for that, they could be talking simply about the support of TFS being included in the Ultimate edition. I'm not sure all VS editions support TFS, e.g. I don't think express editions do.

Comment: Ultimate is only available through an MSDN subscription.  By virtue of being licensed for that level of subscription, there is a download available within your subscription for TFS.  Would need to check the licensing documentation, but I believe that version includes five CALs (and you cannot combine CALs between multiple MSDN subscriptions).

Answer (score 4):

Since the licensing varies by country, the true answer is, "Call Microsoft and find out".

However, in general, a license for TFS comes with the MSDN subscription. Also, in general, the "Ultimate" edition is only offered with an MSDN subscription.

But go ask Microsoft before you find out the hard way that your country is the exception to the "general" rule.

Comment: Call your local Microsoft office and ask.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to acquire TFS is through msdn.  If you have msdn then you can download a non trial server.

Installation is very straight forward.  If you don't have SQL server, it will install sqlexpress.  Also, starting with 2010, it can install on a client os which works great as long as its not a very large team ( client os iis limitations).

You should be able to next, next your way to a server.